# How can I replace <img> tags in HTML with <amp-img> tags?

Tags: php, google-amp

I want to turn HTML pages into Google AMP pages, and I have this problem where I have a lot of `<img>` that I want to turn into `<amp-img>` tags.

For example, I want to turn:

```
<img src='apa.png'><br>
hi bro <img src="c.png'>
```

into something like this:

```
<amp-img src="apa.png" width="800" height="684" layout="responsive" alt="AMP"></amp-img><br/>
hi bro <amp-img src="c.png" width="800" height="684" layout="responsive" alt="AMP"></amp-img>
```

I've tried to replace those tags with PHP, but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Where is this HTML? Are they strings? or they are on HTML Files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use preg_replace to replace a pattern with a string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Try this code:

```
echo htmlentities(preg_replace(
    '/<img src="([^"]*)"\s*\/?>/', 
    '<amp-img src="$1" width="800" height="684" layout="responsive" alt="AMP"></amp-img>', 
    '<img src="apa.png"><br>hi bro <img src="c.png">'
));
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using `htmlentities()` here?

Comment: Juste to show the result when using browser to test the code. When removing htmlentities() function, the result will not be shown correctly because the browser will interpret <amp-img> as a html tag.

Comment: How about using http://3v4l.org instead? For example, see https://3v4l.org/dKcD2.

Comment: There's one problem, though - what about adjusting the expression to also match `<img src="..." />` and `<img src="..."/>` (note the closing `/` with and without space before)?

Comment: Yes, it's another alternative. Finally we have the same result :)

Comment: @localheinz: Post edited

Comment: hi bro,, But i get this url `a.jpgalt='aaa'`, when i take it on the tags `<img src='a.jpg' alt='aaa'>`

Comment: as soon as there is anything else in the `img` tag, this doesn't work. for example, it doesn't match `<img src="peach.jpg" alt="peach">`. the regex should be `/<img src="([^"]*)".*\/?>/` to match not only whitespace but *all* characters between the end of the `src`string and the end of the tag `>`.

Comment: @low_rents your solution is perfect but i have data-src attribute which is not working `<img src="peach.jpg" data-src="peach.jpg" alt="peach">`

Answer (score 3):

I was just in a situation where I need to change all image tags in one meta field (a WordPress custom WYSIWYG field) and I thought this may help others. This code is basically a combination of some of the responses posted here, modified slightly, as the `<img>` tags had extra info in them before the src:

```
   echo preg_replace(
        '/<img .*? src="([^"]*)" .*?>/', 
        '<amp-img src="$1" width="600" height="600" layout="intrinsic" alt="AMP"></amp-img>', 
        $meta_field_output
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If this HTML is present on the HTML file, then all you need to do is do search-replace `<img src=` with `<amp-img width="800" height="684" layout="responsive" alt="AMP" src=`

if you have a editor that is capable of finding and replacing using regular rexpression, use the following regex on `FIND`:

```
 <img src=("|')(.*)'>
```

and following on  `REPLACE`:

```
<amp-img src="$2" width="800" height="684" layout="responsive" alt="AMP"</amp-img>
```

I tried this with Dreamwearver and it worked for me.

Comment: Don't forget that `<amp-img>` tags need to be closed, too: https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/.

Comment: I changed the answer to use regex find and replace that takes closing tag into account as well.

Answer (score -1):

After a while testing regexs, i found an solution that matched my needs,

```
return preg_replace_callback('/<img[\s*]alt="([^"]*)"[\s*]src="([^"]*)"([\s*]?)((.*?)+?)>/',
function ($found) {
    $size = (getimagesize($found[2]));

    return '<amp-img src="' . $found[2] . '" width="'. $size[0] .'" height="' . $size[1] . '" layout="responsive" alt="' . $found[1] .'"></amp-img>';
}, $html);
```